# How to cd to a specific directory in the /etc/rc.local

Tags: command-line, bash, java

I have a spring boot application which, in order to run succussfully, a specific config file must be in the current directory(the PWD where I run the `java -jar`  command in the terminal). (I let my code find the config file in `./`, I now know that it is a bad idea). Each time I run the app, I have to firstly `cd` to the directory where the config file residents, then run the `java -jar` command.

Problem is that I have to make my application auto run after the ubuntu system boots, but I failed to achieve that in a whole day.  I tried to put the `java -jar` command in `/etc/rc.local`, but the application never run after the system boot. Also I tried to add the `cd` command before it, but does not work either.

Is there any suggestions?

the `rc.local` :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
#You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
#want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.

/bin/bash /root/geiri-cmd.sh start defcns

cd /home/geiri1012
/home/geiri1012/jdk/bin/java -jar /home/geiri1012/httpInterface.jar

exit 0
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? rc.local may not be enabled (I think it is not on new installations).

Comment: 16.04 , it should have been enabled, since another python application can auto run after it is configed in rc.local @vanadium

Comment: It will be a good idea to post your current `rc.local` file then. Anything can be wrong, and currently we can only guess. Also rephrase your question: apparently it is not only about `cd`.

Comment: @vanadium I updated my post.

Comment: Looks good, with absolute paths throughout. A `cd /home/user/jdk/bin/java` should change the working directory successfully.

Comment: @vanadium so `cd` command can be used to changing the working directory in `rc.local`? I will try it out then.

Comment: @vanadium please help to check my rc.local, the `cd` command still does not work

Comment: @vanadium thx, it finally works now.